# Group by using month, year in doctrine2

Tags: doctrine, dql

How to write a following SQL query in doctrine2 as DQL .

```
SELECT COUNT(id)  
FROM stats  
WHERE YEAR(record_date) = 2009  
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
```

i.e i would like to `group by` results based on month,year of datetime field stored in MySQL table.

Answer (score 11):

In DQL you could also group by *month*, *year*, *day* etc with `SUBSTRING`.

For example - `group by month (datetime format Y-m-d H:i:s)`:

```
SELECT p, SUBSTRING(p.date, 6, 2) as month
FROM Entity p
GROUP BY month
```